# java chatting program login process

Tags: java, swing, sockets, authentication, chat

i'm making chatting program in java

especially, i have a problem in login process.

this is the code

ClientBackground.java

```
package client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;



public class ClientBackground implements Runnable{

    Socket socket;
    private DataInputStream in;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    private ClientGui gui;
    private String msg;
    String id;
    private String pass;
    private boolean islogin;
    private login_Frame lf;
    private String info;
    String packet="";
    String tmp;


    public final void setGui(ClientGui gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 7777);
            System.out.println("connect.");
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());    
            System.out.println("message success");
            while(in!=null){
                packet = in.readUTF();
                System.out.println(packet.equals(null));
                System.out.println(packet);
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(packet,"/");
                tmp = st.nextToken();
                msg = st.nextToken();
                int protocol = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
                switch(protocol){

                case 3000 :{
                    System.out.println("success");
                    this.lf.test = true;
                }
                break;

                case 3001 :{
                    System.out.println("wrong!");
                    this.lf.test = false;
                }
                break;

                default :{
                    gui.jta.append(msg);
                    System.out.println(msg);
                }
                break;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientBackground clientBackground = new ClientBackground();
        new Thread(clientBackground).start();
        clientBackground.lf = new login_Frame();
        clientBackground.lf.Clientback(clientBackground);


    }
    public void showFrameTest(){
        this.lf.dispose(); 
        this.gui = new ClientGui();
        this.gui.Clientback(this);
    }

    public void sendMessage(String msg2) {
        try {
            out.writeUTF(msg2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public boolean lcheck() {
        return islogin;
    }

    public void setid(String id, String pass) {
        this.id = id;
        this.pass = pass;
    }
    public String getid() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

clientgui.java

```
package client;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class ClientGui  extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String msg;
    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(40, 25);
    private JTextField jtf = new JTextField(25);
    private ClientBackground client;


    public ClientGui() {

        add(jta, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(jtf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        jtf.addActionListener(this);
        jta.setEditable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setBounds(800, 100, 400, 600);
        setTitle("client");

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String msg = client.id+ ":" + jtf.getText()+"\n";
        client.sendMessage(msg);
        jtf.setText("");
    }
    public void Clientback(ClientBackground client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
    public void appendMsg(String msg) {
        jta.append(msg);
    }


}
```

login_frame.java

```
package client;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class login_Frame extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String id;
    private String pass;
    JButton logb = new JButton("login");
    JButton exitb = new JButton("cancel");
    JLabel idlb = new JLabel("ID : ");
    JLabel pwlb = new JLabel("PW : ");
    JTextField idtb = new JTextField();
    JTextField pwtb = new JTextField();
    private ClientBackground client;
    private DataInputStream in;
    boolean test;
    String packet,tmp;

    public login_Frame(){
        new Thread(client).start();
        getContentPane().add(logb);
        getContentPane().add(exitb);
        getContentPane().add(idlb);
        getContentPane().add(pwlb);
        getContentPane().add(idtb);
        getContentPane().add(pwtb);

        setLayout(null);
        setBounds(100, 100, 400, 200);
        setVisible(true);
        logb.setBounds(100, 110, 90, 40);
        exitb.setBounds(210, 110, 90, 40);
        idlb.setBounds(20, 10, 50, 40);
        pwlb.setBounds(20, 60, 50, 40);
        idtb.setBounds(70, 10, 280, 40);
        pwtb.setBounds(70, 60, 280, 40);

        ActionListener confirmListener = new ConfirmListener();
        ActionListener exListener = new ExitListener();
        logb.addActionListener(confirmListener);
        exitb.addActionListener(exListener);
        idtb.addActionListener(confirmListener);
        pwtb.addActionListener(confirmListener);


    }
    public String getidtb(){
        return idtb.getText();
    }
    public String getpwtb(){
        return pwtb.getText();
    }
    private class ConfirmListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            isLoginCheck();
        }
    }
    private class ExitListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public void Clientback(ClientBackground client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
    public void isLoginCheck(){
        id = getidtb();
        pass = getpwtb();
        idtb.setText("");
        pwtb.setText("");
        client.setid(id, pass);
        client.sendMessage(id+"/"+pass);
        if(test){
            client.showFrameTest();
            this.dispose();
        }                   
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "wrong.");
        }
    }

}
```

this is my scenario, 
i execute clientBackground.java.
then, login_frame will be appeared.
i will write id, pw. i will click the login button.
then, login process(in clientbackground.java) will be execute.
so, islogin value will be decided.
in login_frame will check the islogin value.

but, if i click the login button, always wrong message...
i want change login_frame's test(boolean value) when i check the login.
but the value is always `false`. how can i fix it??

Comment: You never close the `login_Frame` through any part of the login path .. I assume that when do `client.showFrameTest();`, you should also be calling `this.dispose()` - but instead, I'd highly recommend having a  look at [How to use dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) instead of using `JFrame`s in this way

Comment: i add `this.dispose()` under `client.showFrameTest();`. but login_frame still alive. and also, if i close the server gui, then login_frame active. i mean i close the server gui, login_frame execute `JOptionPane`. @MadProgrammer

Comment: I can verify that `this.dispose()` works, which suggest that you are blocking the Event Dispatching Thread with one of the calls to `client`

Comment: you mean that i'm blocking the Event Dispatching Thread? so, `dispose()` is not working, and `client gui` is not appeared? ... i'm sorry that my knowledge is too short. if possibe could you give me some solution?? @MadProgrammer

Comment: All your code is running in the same thread, so if your communication is blocked for some reason, nothing else will get executed

Comment: thanks alot. but... new problem is appeared....